# Offset in Facebook photos using Graph API (more than 25 photos)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, image

I can bring back photos from an album just fine using the graph API but can only bring back data for the first 25 images.  Is there a way to bring back more than 25 records or to use an offset and start at record number 25?

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$fb->api("/$albumID/photos?limit=400&offset=0");`

See 'Paging' on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Additionally just to retrieve all items set `limit=0`.  Thanks!

Comment: A limit of 0 will return no results `Object {data: Array[0]}`

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of paging. 
Visit : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

You can choose the paging according to your requirement.

Note: `limit=0` will return empty results